# Consultas en bases de datos NOSQL basadas en documentos json

Tags: javascript, json, base-de-datos, nosql, ibm-watson

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos NOSQL en IBM Cloudant y tratando de utilizar una función js (con la herramienta functions de IBM Cloud) para poder realizar el equivalente a una consulta SELECT en SQL.

He logrado conectarme a la base de datos a través de este código (realizando una operación de crear un nuevo documento json para comprobar que funciona):

```
    /**
     * Datos de conexión
     */
     
    var db = 'nombre de mi base de datos';
    var url = 'url correspondiente';
    var cloudantAccount = getCloudantAccount(url);
    
    /**
     * Validación
     */
    if (typeof cloudantAccount !== 'object') {
        return Promise.reject(cloudantAccount);
    }
    var cloudant = cloudantAccount;
    var Dbcloudant = cloudant.use(db);
    
    
    return Dbcloudant.insert(params);
}
function getCloudantAccount(url) {
    var Cloudant = require('@cloudant/cloudant');
    var cloudantac;
    cloudantac = Cloudant(url);
    return cloudantac;
}
```

Una vez comprobado el funcionamiento , he utilizado cadenas de caracteres de prueba para mostrar información, como la siguiente:

```
   returnString= 'prueba <br> animal:prueba';
   return {"message":returnString}
```

La cuestión es la siguiente:
Cuento con una base de datos en Cloudant cuyos documentos json siguen esta estructura:

```
{
  "_id": "animales",
  "especie": "perro",
  "nombre": "Rex",
  "informacion_adicional": "datos adicionales"
}
```

Quisiera saber si es posible conectarse con la base de datos y, al igual que he creado un documento nuevo hacer el equivalente a una consulta SELECT en SQL para obtener, por ejemplo, el nombre de un animal.

He probado con esto para obtener en primer lugar todos los registros:

```
var tabla= db.animales;
    return tabla.find();
```

Pero me aparece el error: "An error has occurred: TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined"
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Échale un vistazo a [La documentación](https://developer.ibm.com/languages/node-js/tutorials/learn-nodejs-node-with-cloudant-dbaas/), esto te podría servir:

```js
async function encontrarAnimalPorId(id) {
  try {
    //Hacemos destructuring para obtener los datos del documento
    const {
      especie,
      nombre,
      informacion_adicional
    } = await Dbcloudant.get(id); //Con esta funcion obtenemos un documento de la bd segun su ID
    //Mostramos los datos por medio de un console log
    console.log(`El animal ${nombre} de la especie ${especie} presenta la informacion: ${informacion_adicional}`);
  } catch (err) {
    //Si ocurre un error informamos lo ocurrido
    if (err.message == 'missing') {
      console.log(`El documento con el id ${id} no existe.`);
    } else {
      console.log('Ocurrio un error: ' + err.message);
    }
  }

}
```

UPDATE:

En vez de:

```
var tabla= db.animales;
return tabla.find();
```

Es:

```
return Dbcloudant.find();
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Echaré de nuevo un vistazo a la documentación, ya que al escribir el código y llamar a la función me aparece db.get is not a function.

Comment: ¡Con gusto! Y si, me equivoqué, lo edité a `Dbcloudant.get();`